# Why did they play with Alex?

Tags: the-body

In *The Body* / *El cuerpo* (2012), when Eva=Carla found out, that he killed her mother, why didn't she just kill him without stealing Mayka's body and all that stuff? What was the purpose when he is killed in the end? So why that show with stealing the body and everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why didn't she just kill him without stealing Maykas body and all that stuff?

Eva and her father (Jaime Peña) wanted to exact their revenge by killing Álex in a way that could not be traced back to them.

> Álex, now gasping to breathe, learns that eight hours earlier, Eva had dosed him with TH–16, and **his death will be explained as a heart attack brought on by stress.**

- [*The Body (2012)*. Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Body_(2012_film)) (emphasis mine)

They have to make up a plausible explanation for Álex's death. Their entire plot was designed to set up Álex — plant evidence, manipulate him to kill Mayka, and "die of heart attack / stress." Directly killing Álex without planting evidence or a plausible reason for his "death from a heart attack" is suspicious (and makes for a shorter, less suspenseful film). They also get to torment Álex this way, making for a more satisfying revenge.

Comment: I think, just poisoning Alex is less traceable than literally breaking into a morgue and stealing a dead body, isn't it?

Comment: @Mirko No, they have to make up a good reason for Alex' death from a heart attack / "stress." Their entire plot was designed to set up Alex — plant evidence, and manipulate him to kill Mayka and die in that fashion. Directly killing Alex without planting evidence or a plausible reason for him to die of "stress" is more suspicious and results in a shorter, less suspenseful film.